# How to use Ids of the test data factory records in test class?

Tags: apex, unit-test

Created a DataFactory class to reuse the code in test classes. I am not able to get the List of users record id into the test class. Can anyone please help me with this?

It is currently throwing Error : Initial term of field expression must be a concrete SObject: List

**TestDataFactory Apex class:**

```
@isTest
public class testDataFactory{
    public Static List<User> cuser(){

        List<User> UsersList = new List<User>();

        Profile p = [SELECT Id FROM Profile WHERE Name='Profile1'];
        User usr1 = new User(Alias = 'aa', Email='testuser111@testorg.com',
        EmailEncodingKey='UTF-8', FirstName='yhsl',LastName='test', LanguageLocaleKey='en_US',
        LocaleSidKey='en_US', ProfileId = p.Id,
        TimeZoneSidKey='America/Los_Angeles', UserName='testuser111@testorg.com');
        UsersList.add(usr1);
        User usr2 = new User(Alias = 'ab', Email='testuser1112@testorg.com',
        EmailEncodingKey='UTF-8', FirstName='iuqwet',LastName='Test', LanguageLocaleKey='en_US',
        LocaleSidKey='en_US', ProfileId = p.Id,
        TimeZoneSidKey='America/Los_Angeles', UserName='testuser1112@testorg.com');
        UsersList.add(usr2);
        insert UsersList;
        return UsersList;
    }

}
```

**Test Class:**

```
@isTest
private class TestClass
{
    Account Acc = new Account(Name='Test');
    Insert Acc;
    Acc.ownerId = testDataFactory.cuser().UsersList[0].id; // It is throwing Error : Initial term of field expression must be a concrete SObject: List<User>
    update Acc; 
}
```

Comment: Once insert the user, query User object again and populate List<User> UsersList

Comment: check my answer if that approach helps

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The class `TestClass` does not have access to the `UsersList` variable in the current configuration, since `UsersList` only has scope in the `cuser()` method (that is, it doesn't exist outside of the method).  Rather than trying to access `UserList` directly, try accessing the reference to the list that is returned by the method.  Change

```
Acc.ownerId = testDataFactory.cuser().UsersList[0].id;
```

to

```
Acc.ownerId = testDataFactory.cuser()[0].id;
```

Answer (score 1):

The `TestDataFactory.cuser` method returns a `List<User>`. This type has no property named `UsersList`. To get the first element, simply index directly into the returned list.

```
User someUser = testDataFactory.cuser()[0];
Id someUserId = testDataFactory.cuser()[0].Id;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can take this approach to build the test classes.

```
public class TestDataFactory{

    public Static void cuser()
    {
        List<User> UsersList = new List<User>();

        Profile p = [SELECT Id FROM Profile WHERE Name='Profile1'];
        User usr1 = new User(Alias = 'aa', Email='testuser111@testorg.com',
        EmailEncodingKey='UTF-8', FirstName='yhsl',LastName='test', LanguageLocaleKey='en_US',
        LocaleSidKey='en_US', ProfileId = p.Id,
        TimeZoneSidKey='America/Los_Angeles', UserName='testuser111@testorg.com');
        UsersList.add(usr1);
        User usr2 = new User(Alias = 'ab', Email='testuser1112@testorg.com',
        EmailEncodingKey='UTF-8', FirstName='iuqwet',LastName='Test', LanguageLocaleKey='en_US',
        LocaleSidKey='en_US', ProfileId = p.Id,
        TimeZoneSidKey='America/Los_Angeles', UserName='testuser1112@testorg.com');
        UsersList.add(usr2);
        insert UsersList;       
    }
}
```

You test class will have `@testSetup` method which will create users.

And you can use those created user records later in any SOQL query or to run test Method using System.runAs()

```
@isTest
public class TestDataFactory_Test
{
    /*
    * This method prepares the test data of this class.
    */
    @testSetup static void prepareSetupData() 
    {
        //create user records
        TestDataFactory.cuser();           
    }

    public static testMethod void runTest()
    {
        User userObj = [SELECT Id FROM User WHERE Email = 'testuser111@testorg.com'];
        System.runAs(userObj)
        {
            Account Acc = new Account(Name='TestVAccount12');
            Insert Acc;
            System.assert(...);

            Acc.ownerId = userObj.id; 
            update Acc; 
            System.assert(....);

        }

    }    
}
```